# CSRF cookie not set error

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-csrf

I have developed a project on django in which AJAX post request is sent to server.
I have used csrf token in ajax and my project runs just fine.
the problem comes when I copy my project to another machine and run it there. 
following error arises:

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)
```

Both machines run just fine and have almost same configurations for django. Does anyone have any idea this problem arose??
Following is my ajax :

```
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

  function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
  }

  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
      }
    }
  });

  var $chatlog = $('.js-chat-log');
  var $input = $('.js-text');
  var $sayButton = $('.js-say');

  function createRow(text) {
    var $row = $('<li class="list-group-item"></li>');

    $row.text(text);
    $chatlog.append($row);
  }

  function submitInput() {
    var inputData = {
      'text': $input.val()
    }

    // Display the user's input on the web page
    createRow(inputData.text);

    var $submit = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: chatterbotUrl,
      data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
      contentType: 'application/json'
    });

    $submit.done(function(statement) {
        createRow(statement.text);

        // Clear the input field
        $input.val('');
    });

    $submit.fail(function() {
      // TODO: Handle errors
    });
  }

  $sayButton.click(function() {
    submitInput();
  });

  $input.keydown(function(event) {
    // Submit the input when the enter button is pressed
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      submitInput();
    }
  });
```

Please note that project runs completely fine on one machine(django ver 1.10) and cant run on any other machine(ver 1.9.4)

Comment: Did you mentioned <form>{% csrf_token %}
</form> ?? @jatinbhola

Comment: i am not using form to send request. Request is sent on click of a button

Comment: Are you using secure(https) url or local?

Comment: i am running my project on localhost